# How to publish a java web-service publicly?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, apache-axis

In my java based web application `(struts 2 and hibernate 3)`. I have made a *web-service using apache axis.*

The web-service has to return data from the database which will be used by the `android application.`

Now, that service obviously has to be published on a public ip so that I can access it in the android app.

1. What are the options to publish it on free public ip's or domains ?
2. Would it be better if I use REST instead of apache-axis to make a web-service? What is JAX?
3. And for android developers , How a web service is consumed in android?

Please answer its urgent and important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to publish on the web you need to put it on a web enabled server, you can do it in several ways:

1. [Turn your computer to a server](http://www.labnol.org/internet/turn-home-computer-into-web-server/9111/) (thuis is one article, just search in google "how to turn my computer to web server").
2. Upload your files to a free host
3. Upload your files to a paid host (usually for a very small fee)

REST vs SOAP (apache-axis):

I would recommend going with REST as it is more lighweight and more flexible (it enables you to get a response as xml,json,html while soap is usually just XML).

JAX-RS id java API for creating REST web services. Look at the [jersey framework](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is a way to send/get data asynchronously and is used wideley in web applications.

How a web service is consumed in android can wideley vary depending on the technology you are using.

Comment: Not AJAX , I know that I want to know what is JAX-RS , it is something related to web services and a tutorial will do.

Comment: Edited the answer, anyway, you should familiarize yourself with AJAX as well as you will most likeley use it if you develope web applications.

Comment: yep, I have used it in dojo plugin of struts.